# Local Git repos already exists

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I've reinstalled Visual Studio and connected to Visual Studio Online. I can select the existing solutions stored there but it says I need to clone them to work with them. I've already got the files cloned locally. How do I link the account without doing a clone?

Answer (score 5):

If you have not *cloned* the repository, but you have only downloaded the working tree files, then regrettably there is nothing that can be done and you must clone the repository.

In Git, when you clone the repository, you actually get a full copy of the repository history, both metadata and the file contents.  This data is crucial to being able to work with the git repository and without it you cannot fetch changes from the server, make and commit changes, or push them.

However, if you have already *cloned* the repository, say with the command-line client, but you want to add it to Visual Studio, then you can navigate to the Team Explorer Connect page, and in the Local Repositories section, click Add.

[image]

When you add the existing repository, Visual Studio will recognize that you cloned it from Visual Studio Online and features like work item linking will be enabled for you.

Comment: I tried that and it said, 'No new repositories were found.'

Comment: Did you *clone* the repository, or did you just download the working tree files locally?

Comment: The working tree is in a folder that I backed-up. I've copied it onto a newly formatted machine. It contains a '.gitattributes' file.

Comment: Aha - sorry, then.  There's really no way to avoid cloning, as that will download the entire repository (history and metadata), which is very important for use.  I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: What is missing from the folder? Where was the missing data stored?

Comment: It's a hidden folder called `.git`, which is the repository itself and contains all the information about the repository (branches, file history, etc.)

Comment: How odd that that folder disappeared?

Comment: The thing that always trips me up is that the windows zip tool (Send to Compressed Folder) ignores hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when switching from VS2019 to VS2022 because my already cloned repository did not show up.

I had to open the project, navigate to Git settings and add the remote URL of the repository. Make sure you open VS with administrator privileges.

[image: Git]

[image: Git Settings]